# Can Word Javascript API do FirstPage Header?

Tags: ms-word, office-js, word-addins

I've read somewhere that this was still being worked on a few years ago. But does this really work now: context.document.sections.getFirst().getHeader("FirstPage")???

context.document.sections.getFirst().getHeader("Primary") works fine. I know in XML, w:titlepg needs to be on for different headers. But how to make this work in Office-JS? I can't seem to find any example of Office-JS with getHeader("FirstPage") anywhere. Is it just for show in Microsoft Docs page?

Comment: Have you *tried* based on the code samples at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.section?view=word-js-preview#getheader-typestring- If yes, please [edit] your question with what you've tried.

Comment: FWIW I just tested on Script Lab and it does work. Of course, the document first has to have the Option enabling first page headers and footers activated.

Comment: @CindyMeister Where is this "Option" that enables first page header/footer? Thx!

Comment: I don't find it in the Office JS APIs. In the Word UI (I'm on a mobile device, so my faulty memory here) I think if you go to Insert->Headers and Footers->Edit (or whatever the menu point is to not insert something pre-definied - or double-click on a Header) you land in the Header area and the Header Ribbon shows up. There's a checkbox there for "Different first page". Not sure this can be added using OOXML as it's a Section property and I've not always had much luck with changing section properties. You could try, though...

Comment: @CindyMeister This works. Thanks Cindy. I guess I'll just have to manual set "Different First Page" in Word every time. I can live with that for now. I've tried w:titlepg in OOXML with various ways, no dice.

Comment: Glad to have found an acceptable work-around! FWIW, it is possible to set this using the COM object model (VBA, for example). Just if you need something a bit more "comfortable" than having to go through the steps every time...

Comment: @CindyMeister the VBA way was the original design, it was made using 32-bit and then I hit a dead-end when 64bit comes along. And then I read about Central Deployment with Office-js, which sounds like a good way for distributions of the addins to multiple users. If VBA works with Central Deployment on Office 365, I would definitely forget about Office-JS which seems to be taking a toll on my time to learn.